# Can one use the PCP theorem to prove correctness of deternimistic algorithms?

Tags: complexity-theory, probability-theory, randomized-algorithms, information-theory

I am thinking of the equality "PCP(O(log(n)),0) = P"

Say I have a deterministic polynomial time algorithm $A$ whose correctness I can't prove immediately. But say I create a probabilistic version of this algorithm say $A_P$ such that it uses log(n) random bits.  Now if I prove somekind of (exactly what ?) expectation correctness of $A_P$ then does it imply that $A$ was correct?

If the above is not right then I would like if someone can point me to what is the closest correct thing to this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement you state is *not* the PCP theorem. The PCP theorem is a characterization of NP.

The statement you mention is much easier to prove. It says in effect that a polytime algorithm that uses $O(\log n)$ random bits can be made deterministic while keeping it polytime (given reasonable completeness and soundness properties). The proof is very simple – we can run the algorithm over the $2^{O(\log n)} = n^{O(1)}$ many choices of random bits, check how many times the algorithm accepts, and so determine whether the input belongs to the language.

At most you can think of this as a derandomization procedure – if your algorithm uses only logarithmically many random bits, then you can make it deterministic by "exhaustive search".

Comment: Yes. Thanks! Are there other polytime derandomizations possible? Like if there were linear number of coin tosses?

Comment: It is suspected that P=BPP, that is, that we can deal with any polynomial number of coin tosses. But we don't know how to prove it right now.

Comment: I understand that. But I hear of of this implicit idea which I am not able to trace an exact reference to learn from - that even within our current knowledge there are ways to convert a probabilistic algorithm proof into a proof for a deterministic one - under what conditions and how? (any pedagogic reference to read would be helpful!) [...I actually currently have at hand a deterministic polynomial algorithm which is doing something amazing but I don't know how to prove it directly and hence I am looking for this approach to a possible proof...]

Comment: There is an entire area dealing with this problem, known as *derandomization*.

Comment: :D Anything simple/pedagogic I can read off immediately to learn enough to try to use something in a special case?

Comment: There are lots of resources on derandomization. As I said, this is an entire area. You can find information using your web searching skills.